# Git tag only makes the files in the last commit available

Tags: git, terraform

I'm trying to tag/create a release with all of the files in the master branch.  However when I create a new tag and try to pull by that tag name the only files that are available are the ones that were in the last commit.

Are tags not designed to allow you to pull all of the files that were in the branch at the time the tag was created?

Error message returned: *error: pathspec '' did not match any file(s) known to git*

**Update 1-10-2020**

Terraform is the process responsible for running the git pull command and it appears there is a breaking change between version 0.11.* and 0.12.* in that a different format is enforced.

Comment: Tag names, like branch names, identify *one specific commit*. You cannot tag files; you can tag commits. Similarly, `git pull` invokes `git fetch`, which fetches *commits*. Git does not work with files at this level: it works with commits. Commits *contain* files, but you always get a whole commit, or nothing. (pull means "run fetch, then run a 2nd command", with command #2 being `git merge` by default.)

Comment: To tag a particular commit, find its name—its hash ID, in other words—and use `git tag <options> <hash-id>`.

Comment: Why would all of the files be available in the zip that you can download from the release page but not a pull?

Comment: It seems likely that you have a tagged a commit in which all those files appear. Meanwhile, `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command, probably `git merge`* and we don't know (a) what second command you've chosen, nor (b) what commits you're merging or rebasing, some of which depends on your current branch.

Comment: You should share the commands that you executed. That will make it easy to understand the problem.

Comment: Terraform is the one doing the call to git so I don't have the exact commands it's running but I'm getting the error *error: pathspec '<the replaced path>' did
not match any file(s) known to git*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there is a format change that is being enforced when moving from terraform version < 0.12 to >=0.12

The format for module sources in sub folders works using the format for terraform < 0.12

```
git@github.com:myorg/myrepo?ref=v1.15.4//service
```

However in terraform version >= 0.12 the following format is required

```
git@github.com:myorg/myrepo//service?ref=v1.15.4
```

Answer (score -2):

try

```
git fetch
git checkout -b <a_branch_name> <tag_name>
```